# How define a user defined function in MPI which takes several input buffer

Tags: c++, mpi

I need to define a user defined reduction in MPI. In each processor I have 3 vectors, one of them is double and the other 2 are integers. I can't flatten these vectors into one dimension data and pass through my user defined function. Also I can't use MPI_create_struct and user defined datatype because the size of these vectors vary in different processors. I know the user defined function as an example should be like

```
void my_sum_function(void* inputBuffer, void* outputBuffer, int* len, MPI_Datatype* datatype)
{
    int*input = (int*)inputBuffer;
    int* output = (int*)outputBuffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < *len; i++) {

        output[i] += input[i];
    }
}
```

but I'm looking for a way that my user defined function takes several input buffer, I wonder if this is possible and if yes how?in case if I could use struct it should be something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::vector<int>  VecInt_t;
typedef std::vector<double>  VecDbl_t;
typedef std::vector<VecInt_t>  VecVecInt_t;


struct vecs
{

    VecDbl_t val_;
    VecInt_t L2G_;
    VecInt_t G2L_;

};

void my_sum_function(void* inputBuffer, void* outputBuffer, int* len, MPI_Datatype* datatype)
{
    vecs *input = (vecs*)inputBuffer;
    double* output = (double*)outputBuffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < (*input).L2G_.size(); i++) {

        output[(*input).L2G_[i]] += (*input).val_[(*input).G2L_[(*input).L2G_[i]]];
    }

}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int size, rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    int root_rank = 0;

    MPI_Op operation;
    MPI_Op_create(&my_sum_function, 1, &operation);

    MPI_Datatype mytype;
    vecs p;
    MPI_Datatype types[3] = { MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_INT, MPI_INT };
    int lengths[3] = { p.val_.size(),p.L2G_.size(),p.G2L_.size() };
    MPI_Aint displacements[3] = { (MPI_Aint)&p.val_, (MPI_Aint)&p.L2G_, (MPI_Aint)&p.G2L_ };
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) displacements[i] -= displacements[0];
    displacements[0] = 0;
    MPI_Type_create_struct(3, lengths, displacements, types, &mytype);
    MPI_Type_commit(&mytype);

    vecs buffer;

    if (rank == 0)
    {

        buffer.val_ = { 3,2,5 };
        buffer.L2G_= { 0,1,2 };
        buffer.G2L_= { 0,1,2,-1 };

    }
    else
    {

        buffer.val_ = { 4,3,5 };
        buffer.L2G_ = { 0,2,3 };
        buffer.G2L_ = { 0,-1,1,2 };
    }

    double reduction_results[4] = { 0, 0,0,0};
    MPI_Reduce(&buffer, reduction_results, 4, mytype, operation, root_rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    if (rank == root_rank)
    {

        printf("The sum of first elements of data is %g.\n", reduction_results[0]);
        printf("The sum of second elements of data is %g.\n", reduction_results[1]);
        printf("The sum of third elements of data is %g.\n", reduction_results[2]);
        printf("The sum of fourth elements of data is %g.\n", reduction_results[3]);
    }

    MPI_Type_free(&mytype);
    MPI_Op_free(&operation);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'll explain what I'm doing In a simple case. I have 2 tringle elements with 4 nodes and I construct the stiffness matrix for each element in all processors. In this case the global stiffness matrix is distributed.
The connectivity is like below.
Element 0: 0,1,2------>goes to processor zero
Element 1: 0,2,3------>goes to processor 1
You see node 0 and 2 are shared between processors. In this case my local stifness matrix will be 3 by 3 instead of 4 by 4. Instead of sharing the whole vector I just make a vector containing all the nodes that present in the current processor. For example the stiffness matrix in processor zero will multiply by a vector of size 3. This vector contains the local result for nodes 0,1,2. So I define the Local2global {0,1,2}. This vector says which node in global indexing presents in the current processor. Also I defined another auxiliary vector global2local of size 4 initialized by -1 for local indexing which in case for processor 0 is 0,1,2,-1.
For the second processor the stiffness matrix will multiply by a vector of size 3 containing local result for node 0,2 and 3. The Local2global is 0,2,3.The global2local is 0,-1,1,2. Now each processor ends up with a result vector of size 3. Let's say
Processor 0: {3=value on node 0, 2=value on node 1, 5=value on node 2}.
Processor 1: {4= value on node 0, 3= value on node 2, 5=value on node 3}.
Now I need to sum up the result into a global result vector in processor 0. Those node which are not shared between processors will go directly to their position in the global result vector but for those shared ones I need to sum them up and divide by the number that they are repeated among processors. processor zero already has the repetition vector. so at the end the global_result[i]/MPI_reps[i].
In this case the global vector will be {3.5,2,4,5}.

If I can write my user define operation such a way that

```
For (int i=0;i<local2global.size();i++){

global_result [i]+=local_result [global2local[local2global[i]]];
}
```

I can collect my result.
Now I have problem with defining the user defined operation. Because for doing above piece of code I need local_result, global2local and local2global pass into user defined function into a input buffer. The user defined function is like (void* inputBuffer, void* outputBuffer, int* len, MPI_Datatype* datatype). There are some problems for me here. First I have problem with making these vectors in one dimensional array or vector. Because they have different type in general. Second I can't use int MPI_Type_create_struct(int block_count, const int block_lengths[], const MPI_Aint displacements[], MPI_Datatype block_types[], MPI_Datatype* new_datatype); as far as the size of block size is not constant. I hope I could've explained my question more clear now.

Comment: it seems you are trying to "reduce" from a`struct vecs *` to a `double *`. This is not how `MPI_Reduce()` works since both input and output buffers have the same datatype.

Comment: If the sizes vary you can not reduce, because that is done pointwise.

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet I can make the output of type vecs. By the way struct is not my solution. because I will be having different size of vectors in different processors.

Comment: @Victor Eijkhout, This is the point. imagine working with two processors, the result from first processor is result{1,2,5} and the second one result{ 1,2,3,4,5}. Now I want to sum up the first element of result from processor one with second element of result from processor 2. There is a pattern that which ones should be summed up. This pattern requires the two other vectors. So MPI is incapable of doing this?

Comment: I want to know how one can send different vectors or a vector of vectors which flattening is not the case for them to mpi user  defined function. MPI is incapable of doing this?

Comment: Your pattern is completely unclear to me. If you have "{1,2,5}" on the first process and "{3,4,7}" on the second you get "{4,6,12}". Pointwise reduction. If you can explain your pattern to me, maybe I can tell you if it's possible.

Comment: @Victor Eijkhout I added some explanation to the question. I couldn't add as a comment here. Please take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

The line you give with local/global/local translation only works that way in shared memory. In distributed memory you have to set up index translation data structures, and then use gather operations to get the values. That's no fun, but that's the unfortunate truth about finite elements in distributed memory. There are packages that do this for you, btw.

Comment: which way you mean here? "The line you give with local/global/local translation only works that way in shared memory". In case if I use index translation data structures (which I have no clue on that yet) and gather the result then what should I do with shared points? I need a reduction for those nodes which are shared between processors. Sometimes I thinks It's better to leave the vector as it is and don't distribute it, but Then I see the CPU will be doing a lot of unnecessary multiplication which are entirely zeros. Could you please tell me what packages I can use?

Comment: I searched about index translation data structures and I didn't found much things,could you please tell me where I can read about this?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is written up. Every serious finite element code solves this in its own way. Maybe there are some computational books about FEM that explain this in detail.